# assigning a popped class object from a hash table into a variable?

Tags: ruby

I have a 2D hash table of a class type that I made. I'm trying to pop a value out of that hash table and assign it to a variable:

```
foo = @bar[0].pop()
```

However, `foo` is not being populated with the object. I've made sure `@bar[0].pop` actually pops the right object as my original implementation is in a Class method with this code:

```
@test.each {|x| return @bar[x].pop() if something == x }
```

and the method returns the correct object. However, I'm trying to do more actions within the method which requires me to hold the popped object in a variable, and I'm not sure how to do that by assignment or if my syntax is just incorrect.

EDIT: Here's my actual code (stuff that's pertinent)

```
class Candy
   attr_accessor :name, :shelved

   def initialize
      @name = ""
      @shelved = 0
   end
end

class Shelf
   attr_accessor :candy_hash, :total_candies, :shelf_full, :num_candies,
                  :name_array

   def initialize()
      @candy_hash = Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = []}
      @total_candies = 0
      @shelf_full = 0
      @name_array = Array.new
   end
end

class Shop
   attr_accessor :shelves, :unshelved_hash, :unshelved_names

   def initialize
      @shelves = []
      @unshelved_hash = Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = []}
      @unshelved_names = []
   end
   
   def push_new_unshelved(candy)
      @unshelved_names << candy.name
      @unshelved_hash[@unshelved_names.last].push(candy)
   end

   def push_existing_unshelved(candy)
      @unshelved_names.each{|x| @unshelved_hash[x].push(candy) && break if x == candy.name}
   end

   def receive_candy(candy)
      check = self.check_if_exists(candy)
      if check == 0
         self.push_new_unshelved(candy)
      else
         self.push_existing_unshelved(candy)
      end
   end

   def get_hash_key(candy_name)
      @unshelved_names.each{|x| return x if candy_name == x}
   end


   def get_unshelved_candy(candy_name)
      candy = @unshelved_hash[self.get_hash_key(candy_name)].pop()
      return candy 
      # problem is here, candy is never populated 
      # I'm gonna do more in this method but this is the important part
      # working solution right now: return @unshelved_hash[self.get_hash_key(candy_name)].pop()
   end

   def shelve_single(candy_name)
      candy = self.get_unshelved_candy(candy_name)
      @shelves[self.find_empty_shelf].add_candy(candy)
   end
end

shop1.receive_candy(Candy.new("snickers"))
shop1.shelve_single("snickers")
```

Comment: Who does @bar actually look like? How do you use foo later on? Do you use foo in the same method and scope?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, the given code doesn't run due to missing methods and wrong arguments. Can you revise it, please? Alternatively, describe what you are trying to achieve. (the method names in your code give some hints but I'm not quite sure)

Comment: @Stefan yeah its tough cause my whole program is over 3 files and several classes and methods. Basically i have `@unshelved_hash` that's a 2D hash holding objects of type `Candy`. in my `Shop.get_unshelved_candy(candy_name)` method, I want to pop a certain candy out of the `@unshelved_hash` table and assign it to variable `candy`. However, I'm finding that the assignment never happens and I'm confused as to why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `foo` is not being populated with the object.

Assignments to local variables cannot silently fail. `foo = @bar[0].pop()` *will* assign the result from `@bar[0].pop()` to `foo`. (or raise an exception if `@bar[0].pop()` fails)

If by *"not being populated"* you mean a value of `nil` then it's because `@bar[0].pop()` returned `nil`. Most likely this is because `@bar[0]` is an empty array. (maybe because it wasn't populated in the first place)

> Here's my actual code (stuff that's pertinent)

At first glance, your code seems to be unnecessarily complex. When working with defaults-based hashes like `@candy_hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }` you can access the underlying arrays simply via their key, e.g. `@candy_hash["snickers"]`. And since the hash automatically creates an empty array as needed, there's no need to check whether it exists. You can just `push` elements:

```
candies = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
candies["snickers"].push(Candy.new("snickers"))
candies["snickers"].push(Candy.new("snickers"))
candies["kit kat"].push(Candy.new("kit kat"))

candies
#=> {
#     "snickers"=>[
#       #<Candy:0x00007fad03046818 @name="snickers">,
#       #<Candy:0x00007fad030467c8 @name="snickers">
#     ],
#     "kit kat"=>[
#       #<Candy:0x00007f981303a658 @name="kit kat">
#     ]
#   }

candies.pop("snickers")
#=> #<Candy:0x00007fad030467c8 @name="snickers">
```

And to get the candy names, you could simply inspect the hash's keys: (instead of maintaining a separate array)

```
candies.keys
#=> ["snickers", "kit kat"]
```

Regarding your problem, let's start by using an incomplete but working test implementation for `Candy` and `Shelf`:

```
class Candy
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

class Shelf
  attr_reader :candy_hash

  def initialize
    @candy_hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
  end

  def add_candy(candy)
    candy_hash[candy.name].push(candy)
  end

  def remove_candy(candy_name)
    candy_hash[candy_name].pop
  end
end
```

Based on this, we can implement `Shop` as follows:

```
class Shop
  attr_reader :shelves, :unshelved_hash

  def initialize
    @shelves = []
    @unshelved_hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
  end

  def receive_candy(candy)
    @unshelved_hash[candy.name].push(candy)
  end

  def get_unshelved_candy(candy_name)
    @unshelved_hash[candy_name].pop
  end

  def find_empty_shelf
    @shelves.first # replace with actual logic
  end

  def shelve_single(candy_name)
    candy = get_unshelved_candy(candy_name)
    empty_shelf = find_empty_shelf
    empty_shelf.add_candy(candy)
  end
end
```

Example: (I've omitted the object ids)

```
shop = Shop.new
shop.shelves << Shelf.new

shop.receive_candy(Candy.new("snickers"))
shop.unshelved_hash #=> {"snickers"=>[#<Candy @name="snickers">]}
shop.shelves        #=> [#<Shelf @candy_hash={}>]

shop.shelve_single("snickers")
shop.unshelved_hash #=> {"snickers"=>[]}
shop.shelves        #=> [#<Shelf @candy_hash={"snickers"=>[#<Candy @name="snickers">]}>]
```

You could also replace `unshelved_hash` by an instance of `Shelf` in order to reuse its code:

```
class Shop
  attr_reader :shelves, :unshelved

  def initialize
    @shelves = []
    @unshelved = Shelf.new
  end

  def receive_candy(candy)
    @unshelved.add_candy(candy)
  end

  def get_unshelved_candy(candy_name)
    @unshelved.remove_candy(candy_name)
  end

  # ...
end
```

The `Shop` implementation(s) above aren't complete but they should get you started.

A common pitfall with hashes that assign values lazily is that they don't handle deletion automatically. You might have noticed that after shelving our test Snickers, the `unshelved_hash` still contains `"snickers"=>[]`. To remove it completely, you can [`delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#delete-method) the corresponding key after `pop`-ing off the array's last item:

```
  def remove_candy(candy_name)
    candy = candy_hash[candy_name].pop
    candy_hash.delete(candy_name) if candy_hash[candy_name].empty?
    candy
  end
```

Comment: I think this is what i was missing. I guess I just didn't understand the full capabilities of the hash and was treating it as an array instead

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer is based on quite a few assumptions to fill-up the gaps in your question.

You need to use `break` instead of `return` if you want to assign the value to a variable within a method. `return` exits the whole method while `break` only interrupts the current iterator (`each` in your case):

```
def my_method
  my_value = @test.each {|x| break @bar[x].pop() if something == x }
  ...
end
```

Comment: So basically I have `@unshelved_hash` that's a 2D hash holding objects of type `Candy`. in my `Shop.get_unshelved_candy(candy_name)` method, I want to pop a certain `Candy` object out of the `@unshelved_hash` table and assign it to variable `candy`. So I'm wondering why i can't just use simple assignment into the variable and return the variable